# ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC Access Denied role based authorization - Conflict with custom UserClaimsPrincipalFactory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I have read a lot of answers on stackoverflow for similar problems but still cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

My AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles and AspNetUserRoles tables have been seeded correctly.

This is my ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddAuthorization(options => {
            options.AddPolicy("ManagerOnly", policy => policy.RequireRole("Manager"));
            options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
        });
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            ...
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            ...
        });

        services.Configure<PasswordHasherOptions>(option =>
        {
            ...
        });
    }
```

I am using the default identity management that Visual Studio scaffolds when we select "individual user accounts" as authentication method.

When I put
`[Authorize(Policy = "ManagerOnly"]`
on any Action, I get the Access Denied result even when logged in from the correct user account which is in the Manager role.

**EDIT:**

I have verified that the problem disappears when I remove `.AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>();`

Following is my CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory:

```
public class CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>
{
    public CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor) : base(userManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        var identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("FullName", user.FullName ?? "Unnamed"));
        return identity;
    }
}
```

Any idea why this would conflict with Roles?

**EDIT 2:**

Solution for noobs like me:

```
public class CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
{
    public CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory(
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor) : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
    }
```

Per my understanding, role manager needs to be injected in the custom claims factory so that roles defined in the database can be loaded when we override the base claims generation.

Comment: you should maybe try and put some logging to help you debug if the roles are actually correct (fetched and returned). It's probably a good idea to abstract your policy with a handler so you can actually mock and test it.

Comment: @PmanAce please look at the updated question if you have some time

Comment: are your roles found in your identity after the call to base generate claims?

Comment: @PmanAce No it does not. I do not understand why. Why does is the role not picked from the database? Why is the role picked when I do not use the custom claims factory?

Comment: maybe your dependencies that you inject to CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory are somehow different or not resolved properly thus not connecting to the DB?

Comment: @PmanAce thank you for guiding me to the solution. Please add it as an answer so I can mark it as correct. I added `RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager` to the constructor of the custom factory and that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your dependencies that you inject to CustomUserClaimsPrincipalFactory are somehow different or not resolved properly thus not connecting to the DB.

Please make sure the role manager is properly setup in your startup.